# How can I change the line spacing in a multiline caption within the list of figures/tables?

Tags: table-of-contents, line-spacing, tocloft

I would like to know how to adjust the line spacing within a multiline entry? I am trying to increase the line spacing in the multiline entry which is wrapped in the table of figures/tables. I tried to search around but could not find how to do it.

Minimum source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}


\begin{document}
\setlength\cftbeforefigskip{\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\cftfigpresnum{Figure }
\cftsetindents{fig}{0pt}{6.2pc}
\renewcommand\cftfigdotsep{1}
\renewcommand\cftfigleader{\normalfont\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\listoffigures

    
\begin{figure}
    \caption{something}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{fig name so long that it can wrap around fig name so long that it can wrap aroundfig name so long that it can wrap aroundfig name so long that it can wrap around}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

What I have:
[image: Example Now]

What I need it to be like:
[image]

Help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hey Yune, welcome to TeX.SE! I don't see the difference between your example and your desired output. Can you maybe give some more hints?

Comment: Hi Tobi, the multiline in Figure 2 in my example has a tighter line spacing (between individual line), I would like to increase it to match the line spacing like the spacing between Figure 1 and Figure 2 (which should achieve the effect of the example provided.)

Comment: Ok Yune, now I get it. I misread the "between the multiline wrapped entry". I improved your question a bit, if you don't like it, feel free to revert/modify.